# FBX import error

Tags: import, error

I have trouble with importing fbx file created in MotionBuilder. I have file created in MotionBuilder which I can import in 3ds Max and Unity easily, but when I trying to import it into Blender I have an error[image: FbxError]

And nothing imported to scene. So, anyone know a solution?

P.S. File contains a simple model with skeleton and couple of animation takes.

Comment: I have got the same problem. I can't help much other than to say that it *IS* possible to import rigged and animated characters into Blender... but I just can't figure out the magic method. Some characters/ rigs import fine and other characters I am not so lucky and I get this same error. I am trying to figure out what is upsetting Blender but so far no luck. Also, sadly that link to the BOS FBX is not helpful in this situation as it does not support animation.

Answer (score 1):

According to manual, [import FBX](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX) with armature seems to be not fully supported.

But maybe community addon [BOS FBX importer/exporter](http://amyaimei.deviantart.com/art/Bos-FBX-Importer-Exporter-for-Blender-2-77-Win64-621287370) can help ? ([found here](https://darisl.wordpress.com/about/importing-fbx-files-into-blender-with-full-armaturesweights/))